# Android Linear Acceleration: negative values

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am programming an accelerometre in order to measure a distance. I already read that integrating twice the acceleration, the error is very consequent but I don't care about that, I have enough precision for what I want to do. 
The problem is that my position in x axis is always negative and I don't know where it comes from because I move my phone in all directions and I still have negative values.

This is my code that I picked and arranged from internet:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if(last_values != null){
        float dt = (event.timestamp - last_timestamp) * NS2S;
        acceleration[0]= event.values[0];
        acceleration[1]= event.values[1];
        acceleration[2]= event.values[2];

        for(int index = 0 ; index < 3 ; ++index){
            velocity[index] += (acceleration[index] + last_values[index])/2 * dt;
            position[index] += velocity[index] * dt;
        }
    }
    else{
        last_values = new float[3];
        acceleration = new float[3];
        velocity = new float[3];
        position = new float[3];
        velocity[0] = velocity[1] = velocity[2] = 0f;
        position[0] = position[1] = position[2] = 0f;
    }

    xarr.add(position[0]);
    yarr.add(position[1]);
    zarr.add(position[2]);
    tvX.setText(String.valueOf(position[0]));
    tvY.setText(String.valueOf(position[1]));
    tvZ.setText(String.valueOf(position[2]));
    last_timestamp = event.timestamp;
}
```

And this are a few X axis values:

X axis

-0,001147982

-0,003418462

-0,006807898

-0,011325749

-0,01697435

-0,023762027

-0,031681452

-0,04072018

-0,050905682

-0,062279336

-0,07478787

-0,088445522

-0,103226766

-0,119143963

-0,136174649

-0,154338345

-0,17362912

-0,19407627

-0,215692967

Please help.

Comment: Why do you think a negative x value is wrong?

Comment: Also, it would be easier for us to help if you copy and paste the values from Excel rather than post a screen shot.

Comment: I think they're wrong because this data is supposed to return me the position from the (0,0) which is my first value

Comment: Also, I think they're wrong because I wasn't moving my phone to the left (that would explain this values), I was shaking my phone in all directions, I should get alternate positive and negative values

Comment: Are you **sure** that a negative x value means "to the left"?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) the coordinate system is relative to the phone. So if you hold the phone with the screen facing you and move it to **your** right, you will get a negative x value since you are moving the phone to **its** left.

Comment: I was sure until you asked me. Be more specific please I have not time to loose

Comment: I am talking about my x position, not about my x acceleration (the value returned by accelerometer)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are talking about position or acceleration. The negative direction is relative to the **phone** not you.

Comment: Well, i want to, when I enter in Excel and I plot x axis and y axis i'd like to see the trajectory of my phone aproximately, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestions about what?

Comment: About how can I take the values in order to draw a graphic showing the device trayectory. I mean that if a draw a circle with the phone and I always get negative values for X axis, when I draw my graphic I don't have a circle.